Hadamard's lemma for vector fields on manifolds with boundary
1.The proof given in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hadamard+lemma shows that Hadamard's lemma for smooth functions on any open subset $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$: for any smooth $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
f(x)=f(0)+\sum_{j=1}^n x_j g_j(x),
$$
for some smooth functions $g_j$ on $U$.
Does this still holds for functions on a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ in the sense that $f=f(p)+\sum_{j=1}^n f_jg_j$ where $f_j, g_j:M\to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions with $f_j(p)=0$ for $1\leq j\leq n$ ?
2.In page 29 of The Atiyah-Patodi-Singer index theorem by Richard Melrose, a version of Hadamard's lemma for vector fields is used implicitly. To describe this, let

$M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary $\partial M$,
$\mathcal{V}_b(M)$: the set of smooth vector fields $u\in C^{\infty}(M,TM)$ on $M$ such that $u\mid_{\partial M}\in C^{\infty}(\partial M,T\partial M)$,
for any $p\in M$, $I_p$: the set of smooth functions $f$ on $M$ such that $f(p)=0$.

Claim:
Then for any $u\in\mathcal{V}_b(M)$, if $u(p)=0$ for some $p\notin \partial M$, then there are $f_j\in I_p$ and $u_j\in\mathcal{V}_b(M)$ for $1\leq j\leq k$ such that
$$
f=\sum_{j=1}^k f_ju_j.
$$
I tried to prove this by using the partition of unity but failed.

How to prove this?
What about the case $p\in \partial M$?

